# Regexp.match.length returns NULL if not found

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JS regexp.

```
var t1 = str.match(/\[h1\]/g).length;
```

If `str` contains the word `[h1]` it works fine else it shows an error!
How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
var t1 = (str.match(/\[h1\]/g)||[]).length;
```

Comment: Ohh! I had to delete my answer because I loved yours too much ;)

Comment: it worked, will you please explain what this code actually does `||[]` ?

Comment: This solution leverages the behaviour of the OR operator; an OR expression will evaluate to the first sub-expression that evaluates to `true` (from left to right) -- also called short circuit evaluation. In this case, when the match returns `null`, we get the empty array instead, because it evaluates to true.

Comment: I would give this ten more clicks if I could!

Comment: if you need to get the match or empty use
 var match = (str.match(/\[h1\]/g)||['']);

Comment: This is a good workaround for the fact that 'length' of 'null' doesn't just return 'null' or even zero.

Answer (score 2):

how about u do it in 2 steps, you test it first before u get for the length.

```
var t1 = 0;
var string = str.match(/\[h1\]/g);
if (string){
   t1 = string.length;
}
```

Comment: you are overwriting the STR :( though it can be backup-ed :)

Answer (score 1):

That's the way it's supposed to work.  You haven't identified the problem.

If you want to do something based on whether or not `str` contains "[h1]", try this:

```
var t1;
var strmatch = str.match((/\[h1\]/g);
if (strmatch !== null) {
    t1 = strmatch.length;
}
```