# How can I break a custom method chain while still returning a value?

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I conduct a replace on my search variable turning known groups into group names.

I feel like, at each step, I can do a regex match and see if there are two or more group members still in the search query, and if not, abort the chain. This is a function I use regularly and it is responsible to jump out of the process, if there are no matches left.

My actual chain of replaces are 15 long, if I can hop out of that at the first or second, it seems appropriate.

So, I thought I'd write something like this

```js
String.prototype.abortreplace = function (m,r) {
    var toreturn;
    if (this.match(/\b\w\b/g).length > 0) {
        toreturn = this.replace(m,r); 
    } else {
        return;
    }
    return toreturn;
}

tx = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p";
tx2 = tx.abortreplace(/a,b,c/g,"first three letters").abortreplace(/d,e,f/g,"second three letters").abortreplace(/g,h,i/g,"third three letters").abortreplace(/j,k,l/g,"fourth three letters").abortreplace(/m,n,o/g,"fifth three letters").abortreplace(/p,q,r/g,"sixth three letters");
alert(tx2);
```

This works on this specific string because of the p at the end of the string and because I have it rigged to `length > 0`. In practice, the length will be `length > 2`. In that case, it returns `undefined` and breaks. **I'm curious how can I return the string and still break the chain.** (I have also tried `return false` which returns false rather than undefined).

```js
String.prototype.abortreplace = function (m,r) {
    var toreturn;
    if (this.match(/\b\w\b/g).length > 2) {
        toreturn = this.replace(m,r); 
    } else {
        return;
    }
    return toreturn;
}

tx = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p";
tx2 = tx.abortreplace(/a,b,c/g,"first three letters").abortreplace(/d,e,f/g,"second three letters").abortreplace(/g,h,i/g,"third three letters").abortreplace(/j,k,l/g,"fourth three letters").abortreplace(/m,n,o/g,"fifth three letters").abortreplace(/p,q,r/g,"sixth three letters");
alert(tx2);
```

A clear workaround is to simply `return this` when the condition does not match, but of course that doesn't interrupt the chain, it just negates each successive step.

I'm also aware I could so something roughly like this:

```
var groups = ["a,b,c","d,e,f"]
var gnames = ["first three letters","second three letters"]
function chainreplace(query,step) {
  if (this.match(/\b\w\b/g).length > 0) {
    query = query.replace(groups[step],gnames[step]);
    if (step < groups.length) {
      query = chainreplace(query,step+1);
    }
    return query;
  }
}
chainreplace("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p",1);
```

But I prefer a chaining method if possible, easier for reuse (similar, but not identical), without creating more arrays of objects

Comment: You cannot return a value that magically makes JS ignore the rest of the expression.

Comment: …except `throw`ing an exception, but that's probably not what you want. The way you've written the chain it will always execute 15 method calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than putting your own methods onto the `String` prototype (ugh), you can come up with your own data structure to do what you want.

The idea below is that there's one type of object that does the processing you want and returns chainable objects, and when the time comes, it can return a different type with the same interface that short-circuits subsequent chaining calls:

```js
var replacer = (function() {
  function fixedReplacer(str) {
    var r = {
      abortreplace: function() {
        // this abortreplace just returns the object it was called on
        return r;
      },
      toString: function() {
        return str;
      }
    };
    return r;
  }

  function replacer(str) {
    return {
      abortreplace: function(m, r) {
        return (str.match(/\b\w\b/g)||[]).length > 2 
          ? replacer(str.replace(m, r)) 
          : fixedReplacer(str);
      },
      toString: function() {
        return str;
      }
    };
  }
  
  return replacer;
})();

tx = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p";
tx2 = replacer(tx)
  .abortreplace(/a,b,c/g, "first three letters")
  .abortreplace(/d,e,f/g, "second three letters")
  .abortreplace(/g,h,i/g, "third three letters")
  .abortreplace(/j,k,l/g, "fourth three letters")
  .abortreplace(/m,n,o/g, "fifth three letters")
  .abortreplace(/p,q,r/g, "sixth three letters")
  .toString();
console.log(tx2);
```

Of course, this doesn't prevent all 15 method calls from happening (as Felix and Bergi have pointed out, that's not possible without throwing an exception), but it can significantly reduce the amount of computation performed.

Comment: Thanks very much for a prompt and informative reply.

Comment: Thank you again for this. Occasionally, the `str.match` was returning `NULL` so the length was throwing an error. I found a great answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715025/regexp-match-length-returns-null-if-not-found and modified your response in case it's ever of assistance to anyone else. I hope this was alright.